# Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the persists. in drupal after login

Tags: drupal, authentication, registration

Can anyone provide me solution for this.
This comes after the registration in drupal 7 . and user get automatically logged in and get this error.

Answer (score 0):

this module may be help 
[logging_alerts](http://drupal.org/project/logging_alerts)